# (pdflatex) not resolved

Tags: debian, filenames, latex

What is configured wrong or how do I find out?

I expect my pdflatex command to function.

```
$ pdflatex file.tex 
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex: file not found
```

It does not. More explicitly called pdflatex starts correctly.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pdflatex file.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write...
```

I recently deleted and purged with apt texlive 2016. However, what can be configured wrong?

```
$ which pdflatex
/usr/local/bin/pdflatex
$ ll /usr/local/bin/pdflatex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 49 Jul  1 11:07 /usr/local/bin/pdflatex -> /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
```

Comment: What is output of `type pdflatex`?

Comment: @roaima `$ type pdflatex
    pdflatex is hashed (/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex)`

Comment: Ok, in another bash window type gives a different result and pdflatex reacts as expected. So, somewhere in my session the change was not reset.

Comment: See [What does “rm is hashed” mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first command is referencing the 2016 version, that you've purged. The second and third segments reference the 2017 version, which you demonstrate works as expected.

`bash`, in common with other shells, keeps track of which commands are in which directory. (This avoids a `$PATH` search on every invocation.) Now you've changed the target directory you need to tell the shell to clear its cache and start over

```
hash       # Optionally, show the contents of the hash list
hash -r    # Reset (clear) the hash list
```